# Restore of content db fails to restore top-level site collection

Tags: restore, content-database

I have a backup of a content db restored to Sql server as WSS_Content_Live

I have a brand new SP installation setup with AutoInstaller, so we have a port 80 web site called Portal Home.

I have detatched and deleted Portal Home's content db. I have now added a new content db with the name Wss_Content_Live.

CA reports 0 site collections (there's no top-level site collection) and its confirmed when I browse there's a 404 and I can create a new top-level site collection.

I did this last week and it worked ok, the top site was there restored as expected. It is a publishing site if that matters.

Any ideas? I have tried a couple of times with the same net effect.

It has restored since I can browse its two child site collections. Weird?

Is there a more assured way of doing the restore i could try?

**edit**

I just tried again with a restore from powersheell using Mount-SPContentDatabase

again it has  reported 0 site collections

Comment: Did you detach the old Content DB *before* attaching the new one?

Comment: yes and deleted it. you mean from content db manager from CA?

Comment: Deleting from the CA is fine, but I've never had good results attaching from there.  I always use the admin shell to attach content databases.

Comment: tried with PS, same result

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its the way you restore the database in SQL Server

Dont create the database first then restore it.

Instead right click the server and restore a database, and add a name for the db...it will create it.

TBH that beggars belief!